# Proving/disproving that $1=\frac {1}{2}(x)^{-\frac {1}{2}} \Longleftrightarrow 2\sqrt{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I was looking at the solution to this problem:

Find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ for $x=10+\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$.

The solution given was as follows:

$$
\frac {d}{dx}(x)=\frac {d}{dx}(10)+\frac {d}{dx}(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})
$$
$$
1=\frac {1}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac {1}{2}}(2x+2y\frac {dy}{dx})
$$
$$
2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2x+2y\frac {dy}{dx}
$$
$$
2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-2x=+2y\frac {dy}{dx}
$$
$$
\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}{y}
$$

I understand it except for what happens between step two and three. I tried but was unable to prove to myself that

$$
1=\frac {1}{2}(x)^{-\frac {1}{2}} \Longleftrightarrow 2\sqrt{x}=0
$$

or that (I think this is equivalent)

$$
-(\frac {1}{2}(x)^{-\frac {1}{2}})+1=2\sqrt{x}
$$

Can someone show me how to prove it, or am I looking at the original problem wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Nothing becomes 0: you multiply both sides by $2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The $2$ cancels the $\frac{1}{2}$, the $(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ cancels the $(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting from step 2 might help:$$1=\frac {1}{2}(x^2+y^2)^{-\frac {1}{2}}(2x+2y\frac {dy}{dx})$$$$1=\frac {1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(2x+2y\frac {dy}{dx})$$$$1=\frac{(2x+2y\frac {dy}{dx})}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$Now just multiply both sides by $2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing!